# What are the backup facilities of Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, backup

My team site has 5 pages and 46 lists. How can I backup these up?

Exporting each list to Excel and store them locally on my computer is not an option.

For the pages as well as for the list I have a template. I would like to store the templates on my computer locally too. What Are my options?

BTW - I have no rights to use Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SP online has its own backup procedure where you can request restoration of the list, item document or the whole site. The time stored will depend on your SLA. For other backup there are plenty of 3rd party products that can do that for you.